# How to Change Controller and Action Display Names in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, breadcrumbs

I am using to show controller and action name as below to use in my Views-BreadCrumb

```
@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"] / @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"]
```

Output of this query is

```
HrMapPersonCertificate / Create
```

But i want to show different name for controllers. IE : Certification / New Certificate

Can i change the display names of actions and controllers?

**EDITED**

Actually i have some trouble with your solution. I did what you said but ie. in my Person model, now it has two more variable, route1 and route2. Route1 = "Person Information", Route2 = "Action Name : View Person". But i am using the same view also while editind or inserting with using this model. I am in trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using the internal names of Controllers and Actions for displaying routes on the web site. This will make things hard to maintain and customize on the view-side of things (as you can see with this question) and inappropriately mixes the meta-data of your server side with the presentation level.

A better approach would be to create a `BaseModel` object that always contains the values that you want to display in your route:

```
public class BaseModel 
{
  public string Route1 {get; set;}
  public string Route2 {get; set;}
}
```

The setup can obviously change - you could use different names or even a `List<string>` of names to store more than two, but the idea is to not be hard-coding the controller and action names into your view.

Then use pass this model through to every view and use these values to display your route.

```
@model BaseModel
...
@Model.Route1 / @Model.Route2
```

Every single model that you pass to every single View on your site that uses this layout should inherit from `BaseModel`. Thus these properties will be available to use on every single view. So if your current model on a given page is called `MyModel`, just change its definition to be `public class MyModel : BaseModel` and you can then use the `BaseModel` properties as well.

Comment: But i am not able to pass 2 model in a view. I am using this base class in every view. What is the best way to do this ? ViewModel ?

Comment: Why can't you pass a model to your view? You can read up on this [with this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/19/asp-net-mvc-3-new-model-directive-support-in-razor.aspx).

Comment: No I said , i can only one model pass to my view

Comment: That is why I recommended that you create a `BaseModel` class. Every single model that you pass to every single View on your site that uses this layout should inherit from `BaseModel`. Thus these properties will be available to use on **every single view**. If your current model is called `MyModel`, just change its definition to be `public class MyModel : BaseModel` and you can then use the `BaseModel properties as well.

Comment: Actually i have some trouble with your solution. I did what you said but ie. in my Person model, now it has two more variable, route1 and route2. Route1 = "Person Information", Route2 = "Action Name : View Person".  But i am using the same view also while editind or inserting with using this model. I am in trouble.